# Android onDismissListener called on Cancel

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, event-listener

I added an `AlertDialog.OnDismissListener` to my AlertDialog. When `dialog.cancel()` is invoked, the `onCancelListener` as well as the `onDismissListener` is called.

Is this expected behavior? Can I somehow prevent the `onDismissListener` from being called when `dialog.cancel()` is called instead of `dialog.dismiss()`?

Have some code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setView(view)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setIcon(icon)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (d, i) -> {
                    d.cancel();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cancel pressed!");
                })
                .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, (d, i) -> {
                    d.dismiss();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Dismiss pressed!");
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(dialogInterface -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Dialog canceled!");
        });
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(dialogInterface -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Dialog dismissed!");
        });
```

The unexpected behavior also appears in the log:

```
03-25 05:15:31.895 25985-25985/io.l.l D/io.l.l.u.ArrayAdapter: Cancel pressed!
03-25 05:15:31.895 25985-25985/io.l.l D/io.l.l.u.ArrayAdapter: Operation canceled!
03-25 05:15:31.896 25985-25985/io.l.l D/io.l.l.u.ArrayAdapter: Dismiss called!
```

Comment: You don't need to call `d.dismiss`, the dialog is automatically dismissed when you tap one of the buttons. What do you want to do inside the OnCancel and OnDismiss listeners?

Comment: Thanks. I want to do stuff that depends on which button is pressed. Why is this important?

Comment: I added an answer to explain that. No need to use `setOnCancelListener` or `setOnDismissListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use both the `setNegativeButton`/`setPositiveButton` and setting `OnCancelListener`/`OnDismissListener`.

Remove:

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(dialogInterface -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Dialog canceled!");
        });
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(dialogInterface -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Dialog dismissed!");
        });
```

And add the code that you want to run when the user presses OK inside the listener that you supply to `setPositiveButton`:

```
// ...
.setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, (d, i) -> {
                    // Your code that reacts to the user pressing "OK" goes here!
                    Log.d(TAG, "OK pressed!");
                });
```

And similarly add the code that you want to run when the user presses Cancel inside the listener that you supply to `setNegativeButton`:

```
.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (d, i) -> {
                    // Your code that reacts to the user pressing "Cancel" goes here!
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cancel pressed!");
                })
```

Comment: That's ugly, but I guess I'll stick with it. Thanks :)

Comment: @K40S You're welcome :). Why is it ugly? If it bothers you to have a lot of code inside an anonymous class, you can always just move the code to a method of the surrounding Activity and invoke that method from within the listener implementation :).

Comment: It bothers me, that I need to call `dialog.findViewById()` inside a piece of code, where the dialog is not initialized.

Comment: @K40S the `d` parameter in the lambda expression is the dialog that received the click. You can use that instead if you think it's better style.

Comment: Yes, but it's a `DialogInterface` and typecasts are even more ugly. I solved it by creating an interface with a `handle(AlertDialog d)` method that I can use as a Lambda. Still, this is way more code then I'd have when the listeners would work properly.

Comment: The listener is called when the user presses the "back" button, but this does not press the cancel button. That is the purpose of using a listener instead of simply adding another button.

Comment: @LoungeKatt not sure if this was targeted at me or the OP. Sorry, I don't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken It was directed at future readers in reference to your answer. You don't need to worry yourself over it. In a very specific situation, such as the specific use case of the OP, your answer is "good enough"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call dismiss or cancel inside setPositiveButton/setNegativeButton callback, so you can directly implement your logic there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `OnCancelListener` and `OnDismissListener` as a way to differentiate between negative and positive button clicks.

You can implement your logic for each button inside their own listeners, instead of calling `d.dismiss()` and `d.cancel()`.